# ¿Por qué un método de un objeto no retorna nada? (retorna null)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Clase Equipo:

```
public class Equipo {
    public String nombre;
    public int puntos;
    Equipo() {
    }
    Equipo(String nombre, int puntos){
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.puntos=puntos;
    }
    String devolverN(){
        return nombre;
    }
    int devolverP(){
        return puntos;
    }
}
```

Clase agregación(donde está el error):

```
public class Agregación {
    Equipo [] arreglo = new Equipo[10];
    public int pos=0;
    Agregación(){
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            arreglo[i]=new Equipo();
        }
    }    
    void agregar(Equipo k){
        arreglo[pos]= k;
        pos++;
    }
    Equipo devolver(int i){
        return  arreglo[i];
    }
    void actualizar(String equipo, int puntosAdd){
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            String nombre=arreglo[i].devolverN();
            if(nombre.equals(equipo)){
                arreglo[i].puntos += puntosAdd;                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Necesito comparar el nombre de un objeto con un string recibido por un JTextField, y lo intento hacer con el .equals(), el problema es que la variable nombre está en null.

El vector "arreglo" está lleno de los objetos correctos.

nombre es un atributo del objeto clase equipo, y todos tienen su respectivo nombre, sin embargo al ejecutar el método retorna un null.

El vector "arreglo" es llenado luego otra vez por el método agregación con el siguiente código:

```
        ag.agregar(brasil);
        ag.agregar(uruguay);
        ag.agregar(colombia);
        ag.agregar(peru);
        ag.agregar(argentina);
        ag.agregar(chile);
        ag.agregar(paraguay);
        ag.agregar(ecuador);
        ag.agregar(bolivia);
        ag.agregar(venezuela);
```

ag es un objeto clase agregación, en esta misma clase está el método agregar.

Clase main (por si hace falta):

```
public class Eliminatoria extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JButton actualizar = new JButton("Actualizar");
    JButton mostrar = new JButton ("Mostrar");
    JTextField equipo1 = new JTextField();
    JTextField goles1 = new JTextField();
    JTextField goles2 = new JTextField();
    JTextField equipo2 = new JTextField();
    JLabel etiqueta1 = new JLabel("Ingrese el marcador del partido: ");
    JLabel etiqueta2 = new JLabel("Local");
    JLabel etiqueta3 = new JLabel("Goles");
    JLabel etiqueta4 = new JLabel("Goles");
    JLabel etiqueta5 = new JLabel("Visitante");
    JLabel etiqueta6 = new JLabel("Equipo");
    JLabel etiqueta7 = new JLabel("Puntos");
    JTextField primeroN = new JTextField();
    JTextField primeroP = new JTextField();
    JTextField segundoN = new JTextField();
    JTextField segundoP = new JTextField();
    JTextField terceroN = new JTextField();
    JTextField terceroP = new JTextField();
    JTextField cuartoN = new JTextField();
    JTextField cuartoP = new JTextField();
    JTextField quintoN = new JTextField();
    JTextField quintoP = new JTextField();
    JTextField sextoN = new JTextField();
    JTextField sextoP = new JTextField();
    JTextField septimoN = new JTextField();
    JTextField septimoP = new JTextField();
    JTextField octavoN = new JTextField();
    JTextField octavoP = new JTextField();
    JTextField novenoN = new JTextField();
    JTextField novenoP = new JTextField();
    JTextField decimoN = new JTextField();
    JTextField decimoP = new JTextField();
    Equipo brasil = new Equipo("brasil",37);
    Equipo uruguay = new Equipo("uruguay",27);
    Equipo colombia = new Equipo("colombia",26);
    Equipo peru = new Equipo("peru",24);
    Equipo argentina = new Equipo("argentina",24);
    Equipo chile = new Equipo("chile",23);
    Equipo paraguay = new Equipo("paraguay",21);
    Equipo ecuador = new Equipo("ecuador",20);
    Equipo bolivia = new Equipo("bolivia",13);
    Equipo venezuela = new Equipo("venezuela",8);
    Agregación ag = new Agregación();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Eliminatoria marco = new Eliminatoria();
        marco.setSize(600,500);
        marco.setVisible(true);
        marco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    Eliminatoria(){   
        super("Eliminatoria");
        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(null);
        c.add(actualizar);
        c.add(mostrar);
        c.add(equipo1);
        c.add(goles1);
        c.add(goles2);
        c.add(equipo2);
        c.add(etiqueta1);
        c.add(etiqueta2);
        c.add(etiqueta3);
        c.add(etiqueta4);
        c.add(etiqueta5);
        c.add(etiqueta6);
        c.add(etiqueta7);
        c.add(primeroN);
        c.add(segundoN);
        c.add(terceroN);
        c.add(cuartoN);
        c.add(quintoN);
        c.add(sextoN);
        c.add(septimoN);
        c.add(octavoN);
        c.add(novenoN);
        c.add(decimoN);
        c.add(primeroP);
        c.add(segundoP);
        c.add(terceroP);
        c.add(cuartoP);
        c.add(quintoP);
        c.add(sextoP);
        c.add(septimoP);
        c.add(octavoP);
        c.add(novenoP);
        c.add(decimoP);
        actualizar.addActionListener(this);
        mostrar.addActionListener(this);
        actualizar.setBounds(20,170,100,20);
        mostrar.setBounds(150,170,100,20);
        etiqueta1.setBounds(20,20,200,20);
        etiqueta2.setBounds(20, 40, 70, 20);
        equipo1.setBounds(20, 60, 70, 20);
        etiqueta3.setBounds(100, 40, 70, 20);
        goles1.setBounds(100, 60, 70, 20);
        etiqueta5.setBounds(20, 80, 70, 20);
        equipo2.setBounds(20, 100, 70, 20);
        etiqueta4.setBounds(100, 80, 70, 20);
        goles2.setBounds (100,100,70,20);
        etiqueta6.setBounds(350,20,70,20);
        etiqueta7.setBounds(450,20,70,20);
        primeroN.setBounds(350,40,70,20);
        segundoN.setBounds(350,70,70,20);
        terceroN.setBounds(350,100,70,20);
        cuartoN.setBounds(350,130,70,20);
        quintoN.setBounds(350,160,70,20);
        sextoN.setBounds(350,190,70,20);
        septimoN.setBounds(350,220,70,20);
        octavoN.setBounds(350,250,70,20);
        novenoN.setBounds(350,280,70,20);
        decimoN.setBounds(350,310,70,20);
        primeroP.setBounds(450,40,70,20);
        segundoP.setBounds(450,70,70,20);
        terceroP.setBounds(450,100,70,20);
        cuartoP.setBounds(450,130,70,20);
        quintoP.setBounds(450,160,70,20);
        sextoP.setBounds(450,190,70,20);
        septimoP.setBounds(450,220,70,20);
        octavoP.setBounds(450,250,70,20);
        novenoP.setBounds(450,280,70,20);
        decimoP.setBounds(450,310,70,20);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e1) {
        int[] puntos = new int[10];
        puntos[0]=brasil.puntos;
        puntos[1]=uruguay.puntos;
        puntos[2]=colombia.puntos;
        puntos[3]=peru.puntos;
        puntos[4]=argentina.puntos;
        puntos[5]=chile.puntos;
        puntos[6]=paraguay.puntos;
        puntos[7]=ecuador.puntos;
        puntos[8]=bolivia.puntos;
        puntos[9]=venezuela.puntos;
        int aux;
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
              for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
                   if(puntos[j+1]>puntos[j]){
                      aux=puntos[j+1];
                      puntos[j+1]=puntos[j];
                      puntos[j]=aux;
                   }
            }
        }
        if(e1.getSource()==actualizar){
            int localG=Integer.parseInt(goles1.getText());
            int visitanteG=Integer.parseInt(goles2.getText());
            String localN = equipo1.getText();
            String visitanteN = equipo2.getText();
            if(localG>visitanteG){
                ag.actualizar(localN,3);
            }
            else if(visitanteG>localG){
                ag.actualizar(visitanteN,3);                
            }
            else if(localG==visitanteG){
                ag.actualizar(visitanteN,1);
                ag.actualizar(localN,1);
            }
            ag.agregar(brasil);
            ag.agregar(uruguay);
            ag.agregar(colombia);
            ag.agregar(peru);
            ag.agregar(argentina);
            ag.agregar(chile);
            ag.agregar(paraguay);
            ag.agregar(ecuador);
            ag.agregar(bolivia);
            ag.agregar(venezuela);
        }
        if(e1.getSource()==mostrar){
            primeroP.setText(String.valueOf(puntos[0]));
            segundoP.setText(String.valueOf(puntos[1]));
            terceroP.setText(String.valueOf(puntos[2]));
            cuartoP.setText(String.valueOf(puntos[3]));
            quintoP.setText(String.valueOf(puntos[4]));
            sextoP.setText(String.valueOf(puntos[5]));
            septimoP.setText(String.valueOf(puntos[6]));
            octavoP.setText(String.valueOf(puntos[7]));
            novenoP.setText(String.valueOf(puntos[8]));
            decimoP.setText(String.valueOf(puntos[9]));
        }
        ag.pos=0;
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿En `arreglo[i]` tienes objetos de la clase `Equipo` y **`devolverNombre()`** es un método de esa Clase?  ¿O el método se llama **`devolverN()`**?.  ¿Dónde estableces el valor de `nombre`, que retornas en **`devolverN()`**?

Comment: En el código que has colocado, luego de instanciar tus equipos e introducirlos en el array mediante arreglo[i]=new Equipo(); no se puede apreciar que para cada equipo se le setee un nombre en la variable "nombre", por lo que es esperable (a menos que te haya faltado agregar algo a tu pregunta) que la variable "nombre" de ellos esté en su valor por  defecto (null).

Comment: @A.Cedano 1) Sí, el arreglo es tipo Equipo, y está lleno de objetos tipo Equipo, y el método devolverN() (es el mismo que devolverNombre()) está en la clase Equipo
2)Es un atributo de cada objeto tipo equipo, lo instancio en el constructor de la clase

Comment: Revisa que el constructor de **Equipo** esté estableciendo al menos como cadena vacía *nombre*; además que en **actualizar** la variable *equipo* no sea null; si para ambos casos que te menciono el valor del *String* no es null al menos ese inconveniente "estara listo"

Comment: @MarcosMartínez Ya agregué lo que faltaba a la pregunta, en la última parte está el código que rellena el arreglo

Comment: El código que presentas no parece mostrar el problema que tienes. Te recomiendo enviarnos el código relevante que nos permita reproducir el problema. Así podremos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Tal y como presentas el problema, ya tienes el dato que quieres buscar. Si en realidad al crear la instancia de la clase `Equipo` le pasas al constructor el `nombre`, ¿se lo pasas para luego pedírselo de nuevo?... me siento confundido con tu código.

Comment: Has agregado la etiqueta nullpointerexception, es este el problema que estas teniendo? Es diferente a "retorna null". De ser así podrías colocar el codigo completo y la traza de la excepcion?

Comment: Ya está el código completo, la clase principal está al final, solo faltan los imports, el resto está tal como lo tengo copiado en NetBeans

Comment: Si tu objeto se crea correctamente, el método que devuelve el nombre debería estar escrito así: `String devolverN(){
        return this.nombre;
    }`

Comment: @A.Cedano Lo intenté pero aún me aparece el error

Comment: ¿Cuál es exactamente el error que aparece? Yo no veo por ningún lado que tu mandas los datos al constructor de la clase. ¿Puedes mostrar donde  le mandas los datos para que cree el objeto con sus valores como dices?

Comment: @A.Cedano Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: No veo ningún `new Equipo` en que establezcas los valores, no veo ningún setter que establezca los valores. ¿Cómo podrá la instancia de la clase tener los datos, dónde se los agregas?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65463/discussion-between-felipe-velandia-and-a-cedano).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que actualizas los puntos antes de añadir los equipos a `ag`:

```
    if(e1.getSource()==actualizar){
        int localG=Integer.parseInt(goles1.getText());
        int visitanteG=Integer.parseInt(goles2.getText());
        String localN = equipo1.getText();
        String visitanteN = equipo2.getText();
        if(localG>visitanteG){
            ag.actualizar(localN,3);
        }
        else if(visitanteG>localG){
            ag.actualizar(visitanteN,3);                
        }
        else if(localG==visitanteG){
            ag.actualizar(visitanteN,1);
            ag.actualizar(localN,1);
        }
        ag.agregar(brasil);
        ag.agregar(uruguay);
        ag.agregar(colombia);
        ag.agregar(peru);
        ag.agregar(argentina);
        ag.agregar(chile);
        ag.agregar(paraguay);
        ag.agregar(ecuador);
        ag.agregar(bolivia);
        ag.agregar(venezuela);
    }
```

Siguiendo todo el recorrido del programa, primero llenas `ag` con `Equipo()` con valores `NULL`:

```
Agregación(){
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        arreglo[i]=new Equipo();
    }
} 

public class Equipo {
    public String nombre;
    public int puntos;
    Equipo() {
    }
}
```

Luego cuando entras en `acctionPerformed`, que aparentemente en lo que nos muestras, es el único sitio dónde agregas los equipos, antes de agregarlos haces los `actualizar`:

```
void actualizar(String equipo, int puntosAdd){
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        String nombre=arreglo[i].devolverN();
        if(nombre.equals(equipo)){
            arreglo[i].puntos += puntosAdd;                
        }
    }
}
```

Como la lista aun no tiene los equipos correctos porque no ha pasado por los `ag.agregar`, te da que los nombres son `null`.

Prueba en poner los `agregar` antes de los `actualizar`.